# Do SQLite connections share temp tables in shared-cache mode?

Tags: sqlite

If two SQLite connections are opened on the same database using the shared-cache mode, will a temporary table created in one connection be visible in the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they *should not be visible*, but you can look for yourself:
Call

```
SELECT * FROM SQLITE_TEMP_MASTER
```

from multiple processes (one with created temp table and one without) and compare the results.